# Is it possible to use Excel VBA to insert a button to create and save a duplicate template with a numbers file name.

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a improvement form that I would like to use as a template for creating future documents.  I was wondering if it was possible to use VBA to insert a command button onto the worksheet to create a copy and save it under the authors name with an added number so we can keep track of improvements made throughout the year.

Such as having document template > click button > Open user form to enter author name > and click to create new document that is saved in a specific location.

Comment: Help us to help you; **post your current code**.

Answer (score 0):

*YES it's very much possible. I would like to suggest you to use the below written VBA code, will help you to Save the Template Workbook with New Name.*

```
Sub CreateNewBook()

Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim sht1,sht2 As Worksheet
Dim lng As Long, rng As Range

Set sht1 = Sheets("IndexName") 
Set sht2 = Sheets("NameData") 
lng = sht1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = sht1.Range("A2:A" & lng)

    For Each c In rng
        Sheets("Template").Copy 
        Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook

        wbk.Sheets(1).Range("A100") = c.Value
        sht2.Copy After:=wbk.Sheets(1)    
        wbk.SaveAs c.Value & ".xlsx"
        wbk.Close False

    Next

End Sub
```

**NB:** Sheet "IndexName" has Name in Cell A2, which use by the Code as "New File Name" every time you Click Button to Copy Template Sheet. **So don't forget to update Cell A2 with New Name.**

Sheet "NameData" is use to keep track record of New Files in Cell A100 onwards.

*Also, this code will save the Files in default location. If you want to change it, you can.*

*Hope this help you, I've posted this VBA Code after it was tested by me.*

Comment: The OP asked for the macro to prompt for the username when the button is clicked...

Comment: AND he asked for a sequential number to be appended to the file name each time a user saves a copy of the template. So the macro will have to keep track of the user names and the number of documents saved by each user. So even though this code was "tested by you", it doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: @Bandersnatch, yes I've not included the prompt part with this code because most of the time I've experienced OP failed to test & use the bit complicated one. And yes I've tested it and was working. So what I'm expecting, let the OP test it, and if he/she feel I'll include it. Thank you again, you help me lot to improve.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll try this as soon as I get back to work.